# How to get real iframe body height?

Tags: javascript, iframe, resize, height

I have some strange problem with my iframe body height.

In my editor, the typing area is resizable, so after 14 rows, the increasing stops and a scroll bar shows. After deleting some rows, the scroll bar hides and the height should start decreasing. But it doesn't... because I can't read the real iframe body height after the scroll bar hides.

You can find my editor here: http://brownfolder.com/09/ - the body height is below the editor, updated every 100ms.

Btw, Firebug marks the body with it's real dimension, not this buggy one.

The code I use:

```
var s = document.getElementById(rte);
var x = s.contentWindow.document;
var timer = setInterval(function()
{
        var h = x.body.scrollHeight;
        $('.aasdf').text(h);
        if(h > maxheight)
        {
            $(s).height(maxheight);
            x.body.parentNode.style.overflow = "auto";
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
        else if(h <= minheight)
            $(s).height(minheight);
        else
        {
            x.body.parentNode.style.overflow = "hidden";
            $(s).height(h);
        }           
}, 100);
```

**Have you got any idea how to fix this problem?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

```
<iframe style="height:200px" id="if" onload="change()"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
function change()
{
    var a = document.getElementById('if');
    var b = a.style.height;
    alert(b);
}
</script>
```

this code will help u to get the height of the iframe..! this may help.
have a good day.